# Electromagnetic Tensor under Lorentz transformation, $F'(\Lambda x)= \Lambda F(x) \Lambda^T$?)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

Suppose we have a configuration of electric and magnetic fields $E(x1,x2,x3,x4)$ and $B(x1,x2,x3,x4)$, they depend of position and time for a fixed coordinate system. And I want to know how someone in a different system sees these fields.

Suppose this new system is given by a certain lorentz transformation $\Lambda$.

$E$ and $B$ are given by $F$, the electromagnetic field tensor.

So I want to know the value of $E$ and $B$ in my new system, for example in a point $(y1,y2,y3,y4)$, so I want $F'(y1,y2,y3,y4)$ (this makes sense?)

The theory sais $F'=\Lambda F \Lambda^T$, so this equation (which never is evaluated at a point in thexbooks) I think is saying.

### $$
F(y1,y2,y3,y4)=\Lambda \  F(\Lambda^{-1}y) \ \Lambda^T
$$

In short, which are the values of $E$ and $B$ in a different system of coordinates at a given point in the new system.

Comment: Consider the result of a Lorentz transformation...what is it actually doing? If you can answer this you will have an answer to your question

Comment: I have read your question, I don't think it's quite clear.  I think you need to review the meaning of the transformation. Also, it is important to know where E and B come from.  A short reading of special relativity will do.  If you make the question a bit clearer, it will help to bring in a response.